# MongoDB 3.6 aggregate returns firstBatch

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

In MongoDB 3.4 (and still in 3.6 according to the doc), the `collection.aggregate([...])` methods returns a cursor. Then we could do `collection.aggregate([...]).toArray()` or `.forEach()`. And get or iterate over the array of results.

Since 3.6 (appart the fact that the `cursor` options is now required, which is not specified in the doc), the following command:

```
collection.aggregate(
  [...],
  { cursor: { batchSize: 10 } }
)
```

Returns on object with this shape:

```
{
  "cursor": {
    "firstBatch": [...],
    "id",
    "ns"
  },
  "ok": 1,
  "$clusterTime": {...},
  "operationTime": Timestamp(1525344553, 1)
}
```

It's not possible anymore to iterate over the whole results and `collection.aggregate([...]).toArray()` is not a function.
A found a few issues about this, but nothing really relevant.
The doc is really outdated on this and I'm not even sure that this is the expected behaviours.

Note: I'm running it in the mongoshell, but also encountered these issues with the last node driver.

Comment: Hi Cohars could you clarify something? When you say it's not possible to iterate over the whole results, could you describe what goes wrong when you try? So when you do `cursor.next()` and so on, does it stop after the first batch of ten? Or does it not iterate at all?

Comment: Just like `toArray()` or `forEach()`: not a function. The problems actually comes from mongo-hacker et not the mongoshell himself...

Comment: Ah, that might be crucial. So if I've understood you right, you get these errors when trying to iterate the results of an aggregation *through mongo-hacker*, but if you do it natively in the mongo shell it works OK?

Comment: Yes that's it, it works just as expected without mongo-hacker

Comment: Good to hear you've isolated the problem; I think the best way to pursue this is direct to mongo-hacker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems comes from mongo-hacker...

Comment: Same as this issue reported (3 years ago) against mongo-hacker? https://github.com/TylerBrock/mongo-hacker/issues/141

Comment: I thought it was at the beginning. I can't be sure as it doesn't mention the result with `{ cursor: { firstBatch: [] } }`. Also, it wasn't the case in 3.4.